# Custon Service on Unix with update-rc.d + LOG?

Tags: java, unix

I have a java program acting as a Network server. Thanks the the utility `update-rc.d` I have installed a service on a Debian / Unix server in order to have it running all the time without being connected during a SSH session.

Because my program is in java bytecode, and not a native unix executable, I have used the following tutorial to make it work as a daemon: [java as a daemon service](http://mydebian.blogdns.org/?p=172&cpage=1)

The problem is that I don't see the output of the program any more. I need to see the output of the program, as it shows a stack trace when an exception happens. How to redirect standard and error output streams to a log file ?

Alternative question: How to run the java program and have it continusly running even when I log out from SSH ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the app launch command into a shell script and redirect output there:

```
/usr/bin/java -jar app.jar >> /var/log/app/app.log 2>&1
```

But I'd recommend to use some logging framework to gain more control over log files. Something like [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) with [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) or any other backend.

> Alternative question: How to run the java program and have it continusly running even when I log out from SSH ?

You can do this with [screen](http://www.gnu.org/s/screen/):

```
screen java -jar app.jar ...
```

Then after SSH login run

```
screen -r
```

to resume screen session.